# Node.js to Flume-NG

Tags: node.js, thrift, flume, avro, flume-ng

Is there a functional project that would enable moving data from Node.js into Flume-NG, without an intermediary file.

Perhaps I am missing something, I would have thought moving data from Node.js into Flume a more common need but it seems that is not the case.

I have found a number of projects that seem to have attempted this but all seem to have been abandoned about 3 years ago and are not functional with current versions.  There seem to be some that will work with the older versions of flume, but the API changed substantially with flume-ng and they are no longer applicable.

I have found avro and thrift modules for Node.js, and thrift has node.js support now seeming to indicate this should be straight forward, but that is not working, there may not be enough information about which transport/protocol to use with Flume-NG, or maybe I just don't understand it well enough.

Can anyone point me in the right direction before I re-invent the wheel?

This is the current node code I have.  It generates a ECONNREFUSED.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node

var thrift = require('thrift');
//var ThriftTransports = require('thrift/transport');
//var ThriftProtocols = require('thrift/protocol');

var Flume = require('./gen-nodejs/ThriftSourceProtocol');
var ttypes = require('./gen-nodejs/flume_types');

transport = thrift.TBufferedTransport();
protocol = thrift.TBinaryProtocol();
//transport = ThriftTransports.TBufferedTransport();
//protocol = ThriftProtocols.TBinaryProtocol();
var connection = thrift.createConnection("127.0.0.1", 51515,{
        transport: transport,
        protocol: protocol
});

connection.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});

var client = thrift.createClient(Flume, connection);


var myEvent = new ttypes.ThriftFlumeEvent();
myEvent.headers = {};
myEvent.body = "body";

client.append(myEvent, function(err,data) {
  if (err) {
    // handle err
  } else {
    // data == [ttypes.ColumnOrSuperColumn, ...]
  }
  connection.end();
});
```

Comment: After following JensG advice to ask on the list, Randy Abernethy responded and stepped up to implement the missing piece in Thrift, the TCompactProtocol required by Flume.  With this it is now possible to use code similar to above, though the createConnection is an async call and thus client creation needs to be wrapped in a callback.  Much thanks to Randy for making this possible.  It does however at this point require the latest Thrift code from the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Setup of the Thrift Server implemented in [FLUME-1894](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-1894), file [ThriftSource.java](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=flume.git;a=blob_plain;f=flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/source/ThriftSource.java;hb=trunk):

```
  args.protocolFactory(new TCompactProtocol.Factory());
  args.inputTransportFactory(new TFastFramedTransport.Factory());
  args.outputTransportFactory(new TFastFramedTransport.Factory());
  args.processor(new ThriftSourceProtocol.Processor<ThriftSourceHandler>(new ThriftSourceHandler()));
```

To get it to work, you need to use compatible stack on the client side:

- compact protocol
- fast framed Transport

There is already a client implentation in [ThriftRpcClient.java](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=flume.git;a=blob_plain;f=flume-ng-sdk/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/api/ThriftRpcClient.java;hb=trunk), so you don't need to invent the wheel again.

Comment: Not sure how the java client helps in Node.js, other than as a reference implementation.  Hoping your tips above are all I needed we shall see.  Currently getting ECONNRESET when attempting to connect using generated thrift stubs for javascript.

Comment: transport = thrift.TFastFramedTransport()
                   ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'TFastFramedTransport'

Comment: Looks like perhaps the Node.js thrift code only support TFramedTransport and TBinaryProtocol.

Comment: I somehow remembered Java instead of Node, don't know why. Regarding node protocols: That's right. Never used `TFastFramedTransport` myself, but it seems to be wire-compatible with `TFramedTransport`. Did you try that one?

Comment: Found comments to that regard so I will try that, assuming I can find a solution to the CompactProtocol.  I may have to implement in CPP.

Comment: So because of the lack of support in JavaScript for CompactProtocol, I have moved to implementing a C++ based Node.js addon.  I have it functioning now in sync mode but am wondering if it is possible to convert it to an async client.  Unfortunately the only examples I can find are of Java Async clients.  You have any idea where I can find a C++ example?

Comment: No, sorry, but it's worthy trying to ask that on the mailing list.